# Deal with non-independent data

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model, independence

I'm trying to build a generalized linear mixed model with R.
I want to use a formula like this:

`glmer(Detection ~ Distance + Species + (1|Point), family = binomial,  data = df)`

The problem is that my data is not independent: for species B to E the "Detection" value is influenced by whether the previous species has been detected or not: i.e. if I have detected species B it is more likely that I've also detected species C.
Is there a way to account for the non-independence of data?

I am attaching an image of the dataset as an example:

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Niu7Q.png